# incidence matrix of a digraph with a self loop

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

When writing the incidence matrix of a digraph, we denote '+1' if the tail of an arc is at the vertex, '-1' if the head is at the vertex. Is it '0' for a self loop at the vertex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The incidence matrix of a digraph (directed graph)  has been defined as follows.

The values for Mij (elements of the incidence matrix)

{
If the arc head is on the vertex => -1
If the arc tail is on the vertex => +1
Otherwise => 0
}

This is how the incidence matrix for a digraph has been defined.

In your question, if it's a self loop,  then the value should be 0.

Comment: In an undirected graph, arcs don't have a head or a tail. I think the question is about directed graphs.

Comment: Yes @bof, I edited the answer.  Hope it's clear now.

Comment: @Morgan Rodgers,  it is true. There are plenty of ways to represent graphs if someone could look it up on the net. Here as you mentioned, the issue arises because of the directed graph. Otherwise all the necessary details would have been able to store using an incidence matrix.